# no module name MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy, mysql-python

I'm doing web scraping (I'm using miniconda) and I need to import the data that I got it using scrapy to a Mysql database but when I execute my program in Python 2.7 using Scrapy it says:

> no module name MySQLdb

but I've installed the connection python mysql already so I don't know what is the problem...

> Connector/Python 8.0.11 Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer Python
>   2.7

I went to shell python and I executed >>import MySQLdb to verify if it's installed correctly and it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I've looking for other solution and I installed a lot of other versions of this connector mysql but it doesn't work

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using `easy_install` to install on Windows? Do `easy_install mysql-python` and see if that solves your problem

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Why are you recommending `easy_install` in 2018? And especially with Anaconda?

Comment: How did you install Scrapy? Are you sure it's using the same Python installation as… wherever you got that `Connector/Python 8.0.11 Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer Python 2.7` message?

Comment: Also, where _did_ you get that message? If it's not working in the shell or in scrapy, where is it working? Spyder? Jupyter web notebook? …?

Comment: Did you restart the kernal? you can also use .whl file of MySQLdb for installation

Comment: Yep, I installed python 2,7 and I downloaded connector for python 2.8 like I said in the post :) @UmerFarooq I'm not sure what I have to do with that :/ could you explain it please

abarnert that message appear when I execute my program .py in the cmd using "scrapy runspider nombre.py "

Comment: conector for python 2.7*